# No favicons in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

I've just imported bookmarks into Google Chrome, but none of the bookmarks show their favicons, neither in the bookmark bar nor under the "Other bookmarks" menu. Ctrl-refreshing pages doesn't fix this. Browsing the bookmark manager also shows all sites without icons.

How can I solve this issue?

Software is Google Chrome 12.0.742.122, OS is Windows 7 64-bit. Favicons do appear on tab titles, just not in the bookmarks.

Answer (score 3):

1. Try exporting all your bookmarks to HTML (Wrench menu -> Bookmark Manager -> Organize -> Export Bookmarks). Then clear all your bookmarks from Chrome and close it.
2. Import the bookmarks into another Browser (firefox for instance). Then export them back to HTML (this will clean up the ICON property on all bookmarks you previously exported from Google.
3. Reopen Google and import your bookmarks from the new file you generated from the other browser.

---

From your reply, a thought occurred to me that you could instead try to import directly from Firefox with the correct ICON properties already set.

1. Following step 1 above, do import into Firefox next.
2. Within Firefox try to force the display of the favicons but navigating to each favorite at least twice.
3. Once all favicons are generated, close Firefox
4. Open Chrome and Import the bookmarks directly from Firefox (Wrench Menu -> Options -> Personal Stuff on the left sidebar -> Import Data From Another Browser button).

Comment: @Oak, I edited the post. I'm sorry. I hit the answer button without intention before I completed the post. Check the edited post again.

Comment: I'll try, but I peeked at the generated HTML and I didn't see any "icon" property, or anything similar, mentioned anywhere... the only meta-data seems to be "ADD_DATE".

Comment: Very well. In that case, my solution won't probably help since this isn't a problem with Chrome's favicons folder. I'm adding a bounty to your question as soon as it becomes available if no answer arrives in the meantime. I'm also curious about your problem...

Comment: Edited answer to include another suggestion. Very peculiar your problem...